# Rearranging the table and making identical with the attached image

Tags: tables, formatting

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}        

\title{{\bf Your Research Title}}
\author{Your Name }     
\date{December 17, 2013}                    
%
\begin{document} \baselineskip=22pt
\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
You have to write the abstract here.
\end{abstract}  
%
\tableofcontents

%
\section{Introduction}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l |}
\hline
Rank  & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $D_{Crisis}$ & Adj. $R^2$\\ \hline
Low  & 0.70 (0.22) & -0.35***(-43.92) & -5.96 (-1.07) &  36.36\\ \hline
2 & -7.86** (-2.33) & -0.35***(-41.65) & 2.15 (0.36) & 34.02\\ \hline
3 & -4.37 (-1.19) & -0.47*** (-51.19) & 3.81 (0.59) & 43.80 \\ \hline
4 & 2.21 (0.55) &-0.56*** (-55.55) & -4.50 (-0.64) & 47.79\\ \hline
5 & -2.26 (-0.53) & -0.53*** (-49.62) & 8.18 (1.08) & 42.31 \\ \hline
6 & 1.67 (0.36) & -0.59*** (-51.15) & -4.72 (-0.58) & 43.69\\ \hline
7 & 1.84 (0.42) & -0.67*** (-61.42) & 1.89 (0.24) & 52.85\\ \hline
8 & 0.27 (0.6) & -0.67***(-55.98)  & -9.75(-1.15) & 48.15\\ \hline
9 & -2.27 (-0.47) & -0.80*** (-55.18) & 11.85 (1.16) & 47.56\\ \hline
High & 1.68 (-0.23) & -0.98*** (-54.36) & 29.97**(2.36) & 46.92\\ \hline
High- Low & 0.99 (0.13) & -0.63*** (-32.39) & 35.93***(2.61) & 24.03\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**I want to  get that

1. output of the table as I attached the  image. So I need one number in up and other one below. They will not be aside.
2. First  row and last row will be highlighted as the image looks.**

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `stackanchor` defined in `stackengine` package. Then you may write text by stacking up-down, such as: `\stackanchor{0.70}{(0.22)}`.
2. For the double lines in the beginning and end, you may call `\hline` twice.

Comment: Can you please write that in the tex file I attached, then I will get that quickly.